# The variadic template with automatic return type argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, return-type-deduction

I implemented simple code to add all the numbers together, but when inserting one floating number everything gets weird!

How to analyze the behavior of the compiler to deduce the return type?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename N>
auto summer(N n)
{
    return n;
}

template <typename N, typename... Args>
auto summer(N n, Args... args)
{
    return n + summer(args...);
}

int main()
{
    printf("add: %d \n", summer(4, 34.1, 13, 14, 15, 22)); // Print 22 ?!??!? return last number.
    printf("add: %d \n", summer(4, 34.1, 13, 14, 15, 20)); // Print 20 ?!!?!? return last number.
    printf("add: %f \n", summer(4, 34.1, 13, 14, 15, 20)); // It's true 100.1000 ?
}
```

Comment: You can just ask the compiler: `template<typename>int whatis();int tellme = whatis<decltype(summer(4, 34.1, 13, 14, 15, 22))>();`. This says `call int whatis<double>()` so the compiler deduced `double`. Which makes sense because the deduced type of `4 + (34.1 + (13 + (14 + (15 + 22))))` is `double`.

Comment: This is why `cout` and friends are "safer" than `printf` and friends.

Comment: I like `summer` it is so sunny :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is that  return type of `summer()` is double, but you are printing it with `%d`. Result is similar to when you run a code like this:

```
printf("%d", 100.1);
```

This is **UB** (Undefined Behavior). Quote from [cpp ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> If any argument after default conversions **is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier**, or if there are fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @AmirSalar I said, this situation is UB(undefined behavior). You may get any result or anything.